# Troubleshooting "Error establishing a Redis connection" during WordPress migration

Tags: migration, cache, hosting

I'm facing an issue when migrating a WordPress site from Namecheap hosting to Hostinger using the All in One WP Migration plugin. During the migration process, I encounter the following error message: "Error establishing a Redis connection."

Here are the key details and steps I've taken:

- **No Redis Configuration in `wp-config.php`**: I have reviewed my `wp-config.php` file, and it doesn't contain any Redis-related configuration lines, such as `define('WP_REDIS_HOST', 'your_redis_host')`.
- **mu-plugins Directory:** Within the wp-content directory, I noticed a directory named "mu-plugins." Could files within this directory be contributing to the issue?
- **object-cache.php File:** There's a file named `object-cache.php` in the `wp-content` directory. When I delete it, the website loads without errors. However, it's automatically recreated when I access any pages in the WordPress admin (e.g., the plugins page), and this leads to the Redis connection error again.
- **Localhost XAMPP Test:** I also attempted to migrate the website to a localhost XAMPP environment and encountered the same "Error establishing a Redis connection" error.

I'm struggling to pinpoint the exact cause of this Redis-related error during migration to Hostinger. How can I resolve this issue and ensure a successful migration without encountering this error? I'm open to any insights or guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

An issue like this is almost always related to cache plugins going haywire after a site is being migrated.

1. Delete the folder of the plugin that's using Redis via your hosting's file manager or FTP/SFTP.
2. Check if the error goes away by visiting the pages of your site where you usually see the error.
3. If it does, reinstall and configure the deleted plugins in the new installation.